# Laravel 6 redirecting to https://www.example.com/index.php when I press enter in the address bar with an address of www.example.com/profile?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I would think others are having the same issue.  I am on a shared server with Inmotion Hosting creating basic profile pages.  When I put my cursor up in the address bar for example the url 'https://www.example.com/profile' and press enter Laravel brings up http://www.example.com/index.php which is a blank page.  This only happens in Chrome.  I am guessing it may have to do with my .htaccess file?  Below is that file.  Any ideas?

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pollaclicks.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link https://www.example.com/profile (considering it to be example) does not exists and hence it is redirected to http://www.example.com/index.php with reference to your example links and rules written in your .htaccess file.

In .htaccess file these rules are creating the issue :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It means that if the file with the specified name doesn’t exist, or the directory doesn’t exist then proceed to the rewrite rule below.

The `[L]` flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set

Comment: *"This link https://www.example.com/profile doesnot exists"* - They're using an "example". Of course it's not "their" domain.

Comment: I have used to explain the OP that the particular link doesnot exists hence it is going into the rule. OP has given it as an example and I have also treated it as an example only.

Comment: Actually when I click a menu button it works fine.   Its only when I am testing the page and I put the cursor in the address bar directly and hit the return key does this happen.

Comment: As per the rules written in the .htaccess file it is redirecting because of that and strange that it is working. Can you provide real links just to be clear about the problem??

Comment: I am not able at this moment, I would have to contact the team in order to be able to do this.  Unfortunately, I have signed an non disclosure on this project.  My apologies.  I should have thought that through before asking the question.

Comment: I thought this may have been a common issue with Laravel 6.  Let me see what I can do Prabhjot ...